# Position a div absolutely inside a tr

Tags: css, css-float, css-position

I have a table which is used for showing excel-like data. I need to absolutely position two icons in the top center of each row--I want to show edit/delete icons when the use hovers the mouse over any row.

When I tried adding a relative position to the TR and an absolute positioning my inner floating div, the css disregarding the relative positioning of the parent td and simply floated to the top of the screen:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/85aTs/2/

---

### HTML

```
<table>
     <tr>
        <td>
            fooasfdasdfasf
        </td>
        <td>
            barasdfasfas
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            fooasfdasdfasf
        </td>
        <td>
            barasdfasfas
        </td>
        <div class="absolute">
            I should be in a row
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### CSS:

```
table, td{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

tr {
    position:relative;
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

---

I am aware that this is not valid html as it is currently setup, but how can I achieve what I want without switching over to divs with table display properties?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do:

### [See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8pwVj/)

---

### HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="icons">
                <img class="checkmark" />
                <img class="crossmark" />
            </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>fooasfdasdfasf</td>
                    <td>barasdfasfas</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="icons">
                <img class="checkmark" />
                <img class="crossmark" />
            </div>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>fooasfdasdfasf</td>
                    <td>barasdfasfas</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

### CSS

```
table, td 
{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.icons 
{
    height: 16px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #bbb;
}
.checkmark
{
    display: inline;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border: none;
    background: url('http://www.actuary.com/directory/template/default/images/icon_checkmark.gif');
}
.crossmark
{
    display: inline;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    border: none;
    background: url('http://researchautism.net/img/rating_icons/crossmark_sm.png');
}
```

---

### RESULTS

[image: jsFiddle Results]

Comment: This works, but my table is very wide. Half of it goes of the screen. So I won't see those icons until I scroll to the right.

Comment: How would that have been different with the `TR`?

Comment: The TR spans the entire width of the table so I can cleverly position the icons where the user can see them.

Comment: Right, but you have the absolute positioning all the way to the top and all the way to the right, so if it were in the `TR` or the farthest most `TD` you end up with the same thing. That's all I'm saying.

Comment: I've edited my answer with what I think you should do.

Comment: Nice try, but that won't align the cells vertically. :)

Comment: I guess I don't understand exactly what you want.  Could you clarify?